# Get multiple values on JSON with Json.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Is there a function where you can select multiples "nodes" on JSON string?

Sample:

```
var myJson = @"{
  'channel' :  'nine',
  'segment' :  'mobile',
  'food' :  'pizza'
}";

var myObjectFromJson = JObject.Parse(myJson);

var channelFoodNodes = myObjectFromJson.SelectTokens("channel, food"); //<- This call not works!
```

Expected result:

```
{
    "channel" :  "nine",
    "food" :  "pizza"
}
```

Reference:

[Querying JSON with SelectToken](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, your code is invalid with the newlines (your string should be a verbatim string if you want to put newlines in it without concatenating, with @ in front of it, and quotes replaced by double quotes).

Second, you are trying to invoke `SelectTokens()` on a `string`... you need to parse it to a `JObject` first:

```
var myJson = JObject.Parse(@"
{
   ""channel"" :  ""nine"",
   ""segment"" :  ""mobile"",
   ""food"" :  ""pizza""
}");
```

Then `myJson` is a `JObject` (and not a `string`) where you can call `SelectTokens()` on

HOWEVER, what you want to achieve can't be achieved with JPath (which is what `SelectTokens()` uses), so you'd be better off parsing the object directly, something like:

```
var channelFoodNodes = myJson.Children()
                          .OfType<JProperty>()
                          .Where(x => new []{ "channel", "food"}.Contains(x.Name));
```

Then you can construct a new `JObject` from the resulting enumerable of `JProperties`:

```
var newObject = new JObject(channelFoodNodes);
```

Which will contain your resulting object.

You can see it all in action [in this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GdXmzm)

---

If you want to select the properies this way (as you were trying to do with `SelectTokens()`), you can also build a simple extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<JProperty> SelectRootProperties(this JObject obj, params string[] propertyNames)
{
    return obj.Children().OfType<JProperty>().Where(x => propertyNames.Contains(x.Name));       
}
```

And call it like:

```
myObject.SelectRootProperties("channel", "food");
```

See it in action [in this other fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/V328BF)

(or you could also make a simple method which gets the input json string and the property names, construct the `JObject`, parse the properties and return the string of the resulting object, which seems to be what you are asking, but I'll leave that as an exercise)

Comment: Thanks @Jcl! The question was asked in an unrealistic way (I had mentioned in the first version that it did not exist, it was just for example). The idea is to work with JObject. I have corrected the points in the question so that it deserves your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your existing data is a key/value of strings. You can deserialize it to a `Dictionary<string, string>` and access the pieces you want from the dictionary produced.

```
var things = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,string>>(json);
Console.WriteLine(things["channel"]);
Console.WriteLine(things["food"]);
```